# Creating Universal App (IPhone/Ipad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am working on  Application that should run on both iPad and iPhone. It should have different design  for iPad and iPhone.I am using Interface Builder.I've read apple guidelines,but i am still wondering  : IS it better to create 1 View Controller for  2 xibs for each screen   (and handle differences in design in every view Controller in navigation hierarchy   ) or it's better to have  2 view controllers with 2 different views for each screen (and different navigation hierarchy )? Are there any benefits in choosing one way over the other?  how do you do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: strictly 1 view controller for 2 xibs... I hope you don't want to write 2 codes for same screen...

Comment: If you have Xcode 6, use the new Interface Builder to create only one storyboard for both iPhone, iPad and new-sized screens. You will save a lot of time. This will be an option if you can wait for about a month to release your app (and iOS 8 / Xcode 6 are released).

Comment: No I was thiking of writing one base view controller extended and save myself some writing  sharing similarities in design.thanks   that new feature sounds great.  I will cosider it. ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 2 different storyboards that share 1 View Controller class. There is no need to have 2 classes that do exactly the same thing. You are better off having 1 class.

HOWEVER, if you wish to wait a month or so to release your application, I would listen to @Robotic Cat. In this case, you are able to use 1 storyboard with 1 view controller class. Xcode has great constraint features that assist in formatting your interface across multiple screen sizes, with any orientation.